# Display Fields of Object with Checkboxes instead of list

Tags: apex, visualforce, wrapper-class

I would like to display the list of custom fields for related objects as Checkbox so that I can pass those fields selected in SOQL Query

Now I could able to get the list of fields as picklist for selected custom object, but I would like to get it the custom Fields for selected object in the form of checkboxes so that I can select the required fields.

**Page**

```
<apex:page controller="ObjectFieldExplorerControllerCheckBox">
        <apex:form id="form">


       <apex:repeat value="{!selectedField}" var="flds" id="repeat2">
             <td> <p> {!fieldOptions} </p> </td>
        </apex:repeat>

       <apex:selectList value="{!selectedObject}" size="1">
                <apex:selectOptions value="{!objectOptions}" />
                <apex:actionSupport reRender="form" event="onchange" />
            </apex:selectList>

            <apex:pageBlock >
                <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!selectedField}" var="obj">

                    <apex:column value="{!fieldOptions}" />
                </apex:pageBlockTable>
            </apex:pageBlock>


            <apex:selectList value="{!selectedField}" size="1">
                <apex:selectOptions value="{!fieldOptions}" />
            </apex:selectList>
        </apex:form>
    </apex:page>
```

**Controller**

```
    public class ObjectFieldExplorerControllerCheckBox{
        public String selectedObject { get; set; }
        public String selectedField { get; set; }

        public SelectOption[] getObjectOptions() {
            SelectOption[] results = new SelectOption[] { new SelectOption('','-- none --') };
            for(SObjectType sType: Schema.getGlobalDescribe().values()) {
                DescribeSObjectResult res = sType.getDescribe();
                results.add(new SelectOption(res.getName(), res.getLabel()));
                system.debug('--------1' + results);
            }
            return results;
        }
        public SelectOption[] getFieldOptions() {
            SelectOption[] results = new SelectOption[] { new SelectOption('','-- none --') };
            if(selectedObject != null) {
                for(SObjectField sField: Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(selectedObject).getDescribe().fields.getMap().values()) {
                    DescribeFieldResult res = sField.getDescribe();
                    system.debug('--------2' + res.getLabel());
                    system.debug('--------2.1' + res.getName());
                    results.add(new SelectOption(res.getName(), res.getLabel()));
                    system.debug('--------3' + results);
                }
            }
            return results;
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Please elaborate on what you are trying to achieve and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand, you have a list of values and you want to add them to an inputCheckbox and be able to select them in a VF page.

To be able to do so, you can use a wrapper class to get the data from the whatever storage you are using (in the below example, data was stored in Salesforce DB) and pass it to a VFP and show the values in an inputCheckbox.

From [Salesforce developer](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Wrapper_Class)

**Controller:**

```
public class wrapperClassController {

//Our collection of the class/wrapper objects cContact 
public List<cContact> contactList {get; set;}

//This method uses a simple SOQL query to return a List of Contacts
public List<cContact> getContacts() {
    if(contactList == null) {
        contactList = new List<cContact>();
        for(Contact c: [select Id, Name, Email, Phone from Contact limit 10]) {
            // As each contact is processed we create a new cContact object and add it to the contactList
            contactList.add(new cContact(c));
        }
    }
    return contactList;
}


public PageReference processSelected() {

    //We create a new list of Contacts that we be populated only with Contacts if they are selected
    List<Contact> selectedContacts = new List<Contact>();

    //We will cycle through our list of cContacts and will check to see if the selected property is set to true, if it is we add the Contact to the selectedContacts list
    for(cContact cCon: getContacts()) {
        if(cCon.selected == true) {
            selectedContacts.add(cCon.con);
        }
    }

    // Now we have our list of selected contacts and can perform any type of logic we want, sending emails, updating a field on the Contact, etc
    System.debug('These are the selected Contacts...');
    for(Contact con: selectedContacts) {
        system.debug(con);
    }
    contactList=null; // we need this line if we performed a write operation  because getContacts gets a fresh list now
    return null;
}


// This is our wrapper/container class. A container class is a class, a data structure, or an abstract data type whose instances are collections of other objects. In this example a wrapper class contains both the standard salesforce object Contact and a Boolean value
public class cContact {
    public Contact con {get; set;}
    public Boolean selected {get; set;}

    //This is the contructor method. When we create a new cContact object we pass a Contact that is set to the con property. We also set the selected value to false
    public cContact(Contact c) {
        con = c;
        selected = false;
    }
}
}
```

**VF page**

```
<apex:page controller="wrapperClassController">
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:pageBlockButtons >
            <apex:commandButton value="Process Selected" action="{!processSelected}" rerender="table"/>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        <!-- In our table we are displaying the cContact records -->
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!contacts}" var="c" id="table">
            <apex:column >
                <!-- This is our selected Boolean property in our wrapper class -->
                <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!c.selected}"/>
            </apex:column>
            <!-- This is how we access the contact values within our cContact container/wrapper -->
            <apex:column value="{!c.con.Name}" />
            <apex:column value="{!c.con.Email}" />
            <apex:column value="{!c.con.Phone}" />
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```